# How are the arguments being passed up to super in the below code?

Tags: python

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> c = Exception("asdf")
>>> c.message
'asdf'
>>> class E(Exception):
...     def __init__(self, ec, *args, **kwargs):
...             self.errorcode = ec
...             super(Exception, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> e = E(-1, "asdfasdf")
>>> e
E('asdfasdf',)
>>> e.message
'asdfasdf'
>>> e.errorcode
-1
>>> class DE(E):
...     def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
...             self.errorcode = -1111
...             super(E, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
... 
>>> d = DE("asdf")
>>> d.errorcode
-1111
>>> d.message
'asdf'
>>> class DE(E):
...     def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
...             self.errorcode = -1111
...             super(E, self).__init__(self.errorcode, *a, **kw)
... 
>>> d = DE("asdf")
>>> d.message
''
>>> d.errorcode
-1111
>>>
```

Let me explain the above code a little bit. `e = Exception("My message")`, will result in `e.message="My message"`.

Now I create a custom `Exception` class `E` deriving from `Exception` class. It has an additional positional argument `ec`. When I create `E(-1,"some message")`, `E.message="some message"` works as expected.

Now I create `DE(E)`. Now in the call to super, I only do `super(E, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` - note that I am not passing the error code, though `E`'s init expects an error code as the first argument. `DE("some message")` in this case results in `DE.message="some message"`.

Next, the super call is modified to be `super(E, self).__init__(self.errorcode, *args, **kwargs)` -> this is the expected signature in `E`. When this is done, `DE("some message")` results in `DE.message = ''`.

I am not too sure why this behavior is happening. Will be grateful if somebody can explain this.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `super` wrong. The first argument is supposed to be the class you're defining, not the superclass. `super(E, self)` skips past `E` to `Exception`, so neither version of `DE` calls `E`'s constructor at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. as @user2357112 said, you're using super function wrong. super(E) is proxy to E's super, not E itself.
2. About your code, this is a special case:

   Exception is a built-in type, it's super class is BaseException, so when you call super(Exception),it is proxy to BaseException.

   in the derived class of Exception, when you call super(E) is proxy to Exception type.

   in BaseException's init method, if only one parameter pass in, the parameter assign to message property, if parameter count not equal to 1, it will assign nothing to message property. And Exception's **init** just call BaseException's **init**, so the same result.

   errorcode is always a property of current object, so it's always seems right.

   when you call

> super(E, self).**init**(self.errorcode, *a, **kw)

there are two parameters, (-1111, 'asdf'), so the exception message is ''

try this:

> e = Exception(-1111,'asdf')
>
> e.args
>
> e.message

and this:

> e = Exception(-1111)
>
> e.args
>
> e.message